# Silverlight grid (panel) 2 columns 50%/50%

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, layout

Hello I want a silverlight grid layout panel.
The width should be 100%. 
There should be 2 columns that both take 50%.
In the columns there should be buttons that take 100% of the column cell..


Somehow I mess it up all the time and cannot find a way to do this.
Gridpanel is not a must... Stackpanel or whatever is fine too..
One more thing.. the grid is contained in a stackpanel

If nothing works.. code is fine too..

```
-------Stackpanel--------
|---griddpanel-100%-----|
||50%       |50%       ||
||Button100%|Button100%||
|-----------------------|
-------------------------
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: A stackpanel resizes to fit its content. Can you clarify your intention by specifying 100% width on the grid width?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it it:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0">B1</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1">B2</Button>                
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Note the 50* and 50* are relative values (relative only to other star-sized columns), you you can just use "*" and "*" instead. Also defining a Grid.Column or Grid.Row of 0 is redundant as that is the default.

Comment: @HiTech: both points are deliberate. This way the answer is a more general template.

Comment: that's why I said "Note" for the asker and not @ you :)

Comment: I needed to add  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" to both <Button>

Comment: A very late response but you shouldn't have needed that  HorizontalAlignment setting. Most likely there is another Size/Margin/... property setting that should have been removed instead.